# looping gives me the same set of matrices

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Hello so I am trying to run this code where i want X_Matrices dictionary to contain all the X_matrix_i matricies. However, all i am getting that X_Matrices end up being the final X_matrix_i of the final loop. I am not quite sure where i am stuck. Any information would be appreciated! thanks.

```
n = 5
T = 3
p = 5

X_matrix_i = np.zeros((T,p))

X_Matrices = {}
for i in range(n):
    X_Matrices["X" + str(i)] = np.zeros((T,p))

for i in range(n):
    for t in range(T):
         #initial randomness for loop t
         ϵ = np.random.normal(0,1,1)
         η = np.random.normal(0,1,1)
         Covu = np.zeros((p,p))

    #Generating X and e of X    

         for j in range(len(Covu[0])): #covariance matrix for vector x

             for l in range(len(Covu)):
                 Covu[l,j] = 0.7**(np.abs(l-j))

         Zerop = np.zeros(p) # mean vector for vector x

         x = np.random.multivariate_normal(Zerop,Covu)
         X_matrix_i[t] = x
 
    X_Matrices["X" + str(i)] = X_matrix_i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here. First one is the conflicting "i" variables in for loops.
One of them should be changed! I replaced the first for loop i variable with k.

```
for k in range(n):
    for t in range(T):
         #initial randomness for loop t
```

The second problem is that by doing

```
X_Matrices["X" + str(i)] = X_matrix_i
```

(last line) you are referencing X_Matrices["X" + str(i)] to X_matrix_i! The issue with mutable objects in Python happens! Instead of doing so, you should use shallow copy to assign values to X_Matrices["X" + str(i)]. So a copy of X_matrix_i will be assigned, not X_matrix_i itself.

I replaced the last line with

```
X_Matrices["X" + str(k)][:] = X_matrix_i
```

and the problem solved.
[:] acts as shallow copy here.

Comment: Hello Mohammad:)!

That fixed it which helps a lot! have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by the redeclaration of **i** in the second for loop

```py
         for j in range(len(Covu[0])): #covariance matrix for vector x

             for i in range(len(Covu)):
                 Covu[i,j] = 0.7**(np.abs(i-j))
```

Try to rename the **i** to something else and it should solve your problem.

Comment: hello ekrem. I tried doing that and i just edited the code, all X_Matrices are still simply giving me the X_matrix_i for the final loop of i. I would want for after each t-loop, "X0,...Xi" would be based on each of those t-loops.